# How to do matrix multiplication with a Pandas series and a numpy array and always return a Series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix-multiplication, series

I noticed an inconsistency between different Numpy versions when you pass `np.matmul` a Pandas Series as one of its arguments.

In Python 3.6 with Numpy version 1.16.4

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = np.array(range(9)).reshape((3, 3))
>>> b = np.array([2]*3)
>>> np.matmul(b, a)                                                                                        
array([18, 24, 30])
>>> b2 = pd.Series(b)
>>> np.matmul(b2, a)
0    18
1    24
2    30
dtype: int64
```

(Returns a series)

In Python 3.7 with Numpy 1.15.4

```
>>> a = np.array(range(9)).reshape((3, 3))
>>> b = np.array([2]*3)
>>> np.matmul(b, a)                                                                                        
array([18, 24, 30])
>>> b2 = pd.Series(b)
>>> np.matmul(b2, a)
array([18, 24, 30])
```

(Returns an array)

Is it wrong to pass a `pd.Series` to `matmul`?  I always assumed pandas and numpy objects are interchangeable (as long as the shapes match).

Possible solutions (what's the difference?):

```
pd.Series(b2.dot(a), index=b2.index)
pd.Series(np.matmul(b2, a), index=b2.index)
pd.Series(np.matmul(b2.values, a), index=b2.index)
```

(Ultimately I want to return the result as a `pd.Series`)

Comment: They look pretty identical to me.

Comment: Tenet 2 of the [zen of python](https://zen-of-python.info/explicit-is-better-than-implicit.html#2) is "Explicit is better than implicit". If you want to always return a series, then it's always better to explicitly use the call to `pd.Series()` to remove any ambiguities or, as you found, changes between versions or environments. By the same token, I would (all things being equal) choose the third of your options, as that explicitly passes only the values and casts to series (though in pandas 0.24 that would rather be `b2.to_numpy()`)

Comment: According to `numpy` release notes, `matmul` is now `ufunc`, and accepts object dtype arrays.  The earlier version probably does `np.asarray(b2)` and does a pure `numpy` calculation.  One or both of these changes preserves the `type/class` of `b2` in the newer code.

Comment: `b2` stores its `_values` as a `ndarray`, but it is not a subclass of `ndarray`.  Look at the code for `b2.dot` to get an idea of pandas handles calculations with mixed types.

Comment: In my version of numpy, `b2.__matmul__(other)` (the @ operator) delegates the action to `self.dot(other)`.  Since `Series` are 1d (and Dataframe 2d), there isn't any real advantage to using `matmul` over `dot`.  The big thing that `matmul` adds is an ability to do `dot` over batches (i.e. with 3d arrays).

Comment: @hpaulj Good point.  And just realized that `np.dot` is consistent between both my numpy versions (always returns `ndarray`) unlike `np.matmul`.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Based on your advice I implemented `pd.Series(b2.dot(a), index=b2.index)`.  @hpaul if you want to make this into an answer I will mark it as the best answer.

Comment: I can't get `np.matmul(b2, a)` to produce a Series.  I had numpy 1.16.4, and just up dated it to 1.17.0, and still produces an array.  A DataFrame with @ will produce a dataframe, but not a Series.  Both delegate to `dot`, which takes different approaches depending  on `self` and `other`.  My pandas version is 0.25.0

Comment: Strange.  I get a series with `np.__version__ '1.16.4'` and `pd.__version__ '0.24.2'`.  Also, `type(np.matmul)` is `<class 'numpy.ufunc'>` when this happens, but in my `np.__version__ 1.15.4` interpreter, `type(np.matmul)` is `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>` or `built-in function matmul in module numpy.core.multiarray`

Comment: I do get a Series when the `other` is a DataFrame, e.g. `b2.dot(pd.DataFrame(a))`.  In that case it returns `self._constructor(np.dot(...).__finalize__(self)`.  In all other cases it returns `np.dot(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Base on the document

> scalar, Series or numpy.ndarray Return the dot product of the Series
>   and other if other is a Series, the Series of the dot product of
>   Series and each rows of other if other is a DataFrame or a
>   numpy.ndarray between the Series and each columns of the numpy array.

Environment

```
pd.__version__
Out[667]: '0.25.0'
np.__version__
Out[668]: '1.16.4'
```

So that is normal behavior when you `dot` `pd.Series`  with `numpy` `ndarray`

I will recommend check with the timing

```
%timeit pd.Series(b2.dot(a), index=b2.index)
10000 loops, best of 3: 74 µs per loop
%timeit pd.Series(np.matmul(b2, a), index=b2.index)
10000 loops, best of 3: 113 µs per loop
%timeit pd.Series(np.matmul(b2.values, a), index=b2.index)
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks.  I checked timings and found them very variable.  `np.matmul(b, a)` took 207, 205, 149 µs (for a 1000x1000 array) and `pd.Series(b.dot(a), index=b.index) ` took 170, 237, 185 µs.  Unclear which is faster.